# How to interweave input from textboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is my first post here and I am pretty new to coding in general so bear with me.  I am trying to get user input from two different textboxes and interweave them once a button is clicked.  So if the user enters "abcd" in the first textbox and "1234" in the second, the result would be "a1b2c3d4" in the last textbox.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
    <input id="userInput1" type="text" />
    <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
    <input id="userInput2" type="text" />
    <button id="myBTN" type="button">Try it</button>
    <label for="output">Result: </label><input id="output" type="text"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myBTN");
myButton.addEventListener("click", merge);
function merge() {
  var a = document.getElementById("userInput1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("userInput2").value;
  var aMod = a.split("");
  var bMod = b.split("");
  var c = ""
  for (i=0; i < aMod || i < bMod; i++)  {
    if (i < aMod)
    c += aMod[i];
    if (i < bMod)
    c += bMod[i];
  }
  return c;
  document.getElementbyId("output").value = "c";
}
```

I'm not getting any errors when I try to execute it, but nothing will happen when I click the button. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: start with creating 'jsfiddle' with your code for everyone could run it and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your script, which is natural for a beginner, so don't get disheartened.

---

**Missing semi-colon**

On line 8 of your Javascript you don't end your lie with a semicolon. I believe this isn't a critical issue in Javascript, but it's certainly good practice.

**Missing var**

In your `for` loop you use the variable `i` without declaring it first ([`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)). This means `i` is declared in the global scope, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

**Treating aMod and bMod as integers, not arrays**

Your variables `aMod` and `bMod` are arrays, not integers. In order to compare them to `i` you need to compare their `.length`

**You have included a return statement which breaks program flow**

You only need a return statement if you're returning a value to be used later on. Since the function `merge()` assigns the value `c` to the element `output` in it's final line, you don't need the return statement.

**getElementById is case sensitive**

In your final line you have written `getElementbyId` not `getElementById` (note the letter `B`)

**You are assigning the value "c" not the variable `c`**

Also in your final line, you are assigning the string value "c" to your element `output`, not the variable `c`.

---

In summary, this code demonstrates the changes above:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myBTN");
myButton.addEventListener("click", merge);
function merge() {
    var a = document.getElementById("userInput1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("userInput2").value;
    var aMod = a.split("");
    var bMod = b.split("");
    var c = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(aMod.length, bMod.length); i++)  {
        if (i < aMod.length)
            c += aMod[i];
        if (i < bMod.length)
            c += bMod[i];
    }

    document.getElementById("output").value = c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! It's working great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `split()` and dealing with arrays you could use `length` and `charAt()` to provide the desired output.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("myBTN");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let a = document.getElementById("userInput1").value;
  let b = document.getElementById("userInput2").value;  
  let aLength = a.length;
  let bLength = b.length;
  let maxLength = Math.max(aLength,bLength);
  let c = ""
  for (let i=0; i < maxLength; i++)  {
    c += a.charAt(i);
    c += b.charAt(i);
  }
  document.getElementById("output").value = c;
});
```

```html
<label>Enter Text Here:</label>
    <input id="userInput1" type="text" />
    <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
    <input id="userInput2" type="text" />
    <button id="myBTN" type="button">Try it</button>
    <label for="output">Result: </label><input id="output" type="text"/>
```